# Joining Tables based off LIKE words

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables that list out companies. There are 1000s of companies in table a but only about 150 in table b. Unfortunately, the companies are written a bit differently in each of the tables. For example, table a might have ' Walmart, INC.' while table b might just have 'Walmart'. Is there a way to join these two tables off the first word in the company name for each?

Comment: You can join on LIKE expressions, although the query will likely run slowly.  What have you tried so far?  Also, should table structures (with at least key fields).   Is this a one time update or an ongoing query?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.company_name LIKE CONCAT('%', B.company_name, '%');
```

Comment: Not, this will not work if Table B has "Walmart, INC." and table A has "Walmart"

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT` and `CHARINDEX` will do the job, if each company is separated with the following character ','

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.company_name = LEFT(A.company_name, CHARINDEX(',', A.company_name) - 1);
```